# Changing value of a variable within an if statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm having a problem with a piece of code and it's driving me nuts. I've been stuck on this for hours, and the worst part is that I'm assuming it's really simple; I just can't figure it out.

I'm trying to make a simple event calendar using Javascript/jQuery. This is the simplified code that I have:

```
var currentMonth = 1;
if (currentMonth == 1) {
    $("#prev-month").click( function() {
        currentMonth = 12;
    });
    $("#next-month").click( function() {
        currentMonth = 2;
    });
}
if ( currentMonth == 2) {
    $("#prev-month").click( function() {
        currentMonth = 1;
    });
    $("#next-month").click( function() {
        currentMonth = 3;
    });
}
if ( currentMonth == 3) {
    $("#prev-month").click( function() {
        currentMonth = 2;
    });
    $("#next-month").click( function() {
        currentMonth = 4;
    });
}
if ( currentMonth == 4) {
    $("#prev-month").click( function() {
        currentMonth = 3;
    });
    $("#next-month").click( function() {
        currentMonth = 5;
    });
}
```

Now, every time I click the button with the ID "next-month", it is always 2. If I click the button with the ID "prev-month", it is always 12. It never changes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your script code is only run once. You aren't changing the click handlers after you clicked them, so those handlers will always give the same results.

But instead of fixing that it would be simpler to use a single handler for each button and using arithmetic to calculate the next/previous month instead of having 12 handlers which you change at runtime.

```
$("#prev-month").click( function() {
    currentMonth = (currentMonth - 1) || 12;
});
$("#next-month").click( function() {
    currentMonth = currentMonth % 12 + 1;
});
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I thin it's fixed now, though I don't particularly like the `+ 10`. The 10 is a "magic number" that seems to appear from nowhere. Probably best to write out the code more explicitly like Neysor's answer.

Comment: Personally, I would use one handler and a closure scope for the variable, instead of the (implied) global scope. If it needs to be used externally, `$(this).parent().data('data-current-month', currentMonth)`.

Comment: Instead of the magic number, you could do `(currentMonth - 1) % 12 || 12;`

Comment: ...or actually just this... `(currentMonth - 1) || 12;`

Comment: @amnotiam: That's nice! Thanks.

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much. I used this with the rest of the code I had an it worked absolutely beautifully. This was driving me nuts and you just made my day much better. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

you are using the `.click()` function wrong. You should make it like this:

```
var currentMonth = 1;

$("#prev-month").click(function() {
    currentMonth--;
    if (currentMonth == 0) {
        currentMonth = 12;
    }
}
$("#next-month").click(function() {
    currentMonth++
    if (currentMonth == 13) {
        currentMonth = 1;
    }
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for this code as well. I didn't realize that I had to put the statement inside of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closure to store your reference and only one click handler (using `$(this).is()`):

```
<div>
    Current Month: <input type="text" id="current-month"/>
    <button id="prev-month">Previous Month</button>
    <button id="next-month">Next Month</button>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentMonth = 1,
        $currentmonth = $('#current-month');

    $currentmonth.val(currentMonth);

    $("#prev-month, #next-month").click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.is('#prev-month')) {
            currentMonth = currentMonth - 1;
        } else {
            currentMonth = currentMonth + 1;
        }

        if (currentMonth == 0) {
            currentMonth = 12;
        } else if (currentMonth > 12) {
            currentMonth = 1;
        }

        $currentmonth.val(currentMonth);

        console.log('Current Month: ' + currentMonth);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pCs2G/